# how to display spinner without http service call in angular 4

Tags: angular, promise, spinner

In my angular app, I want to return either an obervable or subscription or promise without making an http call.
While that function that is returning any of them, i need to show a spinner. I tried the following way, but no luck.
I am not able to see spinner in this.busy1, but I can see spinner in  this.busy.
Both this.component.processFunc() and this.processData() can be clubbed into one promise.
But the execution should be 
step1:this.component.processFunc()
step2: this.processData()

TS.FILE

```
 busy: Promise<any>;
busy1: Promise<any>;
 @ViewChild('component') ComponentView;
              this.busy1 = this.asyncPromiseViewtest().then(data => {
                 //do some stuff
              });

                asyncPromiseViewtest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(this.component.processFunc());
    });
  }

this.busy = this.asyncPromise().then(data => { //do some stuff }); 
asyncPromise() { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 resolve(this.processData()); 
}); 

processData() { 
//no promise return //do some logic }

HTML:
  <div [ngBusy]="{busy: [busy, busy1], backdrop: true, delay: 200, minDuration: 600}">
```

Comment: I infer that `this.component.processFunc()` and `this.processData()` are synchronous but lengthy processes and you wish to display a spinner while they are underway. Is that correct?

Comment: @Roamer, they are synchronous, one has to wait for the other. I need to display spinner